# How to create different asp.net User Profiles

Tags: asp.net, profiles

Is possible define different profiles a the same time?
I have two type of users in my web site and they have different properties.
Using asp.net profile is possible to define two or more profiles with distinct properties?

Answer (score 0):

If you have different *types* of users in your app, you probably want to look at [ASP.NET Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.aspx).

Comment: Yes roles are like "user types". But the question is a bit different.
If I would have two roles "a" and "b", is it possible to assign different properties to each role using the built in asp.net profile provider? 
For example, users in role "a" have the "CreditCardNumber" custom property and users in role "b" have the "CellPhoneNumber" property. Follow that users in role "a" haven't the "CellPhoneNumber" property and users in role "b" haven't the "CreditCardNumber".
Hope it is clear. :)